# Does Excel have a built-in "hypothetical" function?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel cell with a complicated formula relating to many other cells.

Does a function exist that would allow me to look at what the value of that cell would be if I changed the value of another cell to a certain value?

Basically, I'm looking for the functionality of a simple data table in a function I can put directly in a cell.  I can do this in VBA or by creating a data table, but I'm looking for a built-in method if one exists.

Comment: Can't you just read the current value, then change it, read the effects elsewhere, then set the value back to what it was at the start?

Comment: Will the [scenarios support](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/excel2007/excel2007s7p3.html) do what you want?

Comment: @sarnold: great tip! IMHO, this is worth an answer for better readability of the thread

Comment: Solver might be worth a look. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/about-solver-HP005198368.aspx

Comment: Hi Ben, please go over your previous questions and accept appropriate answers.  This encourages more people to respond to your questions.  To accept an answer, click the tick sign under the voting options to the left of the answer.  Thanks.

Comment: @psynnott, not sure why stackoverflow wasn't notifying me of the new activity.  sarnold, unfortunately no, scenarios won't work; they are not automated.  And even the VBA approach doesn't work; I was going to use the code in my next comment, but it doesn't work because Excel doesn't allow VBA functions that are called from the worksheet to modify the worksheet.  So, apparently the only possible solution is data tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

As you have mentioned, you would be best served using a data table - there isn't an equivalent inbuilt function. The plus with data tables is that you can explicitly control their calculation

Answer (score 0):

@brettdj's answer is correct.  Unfortunately, I was wrong that I could do what I want even in VBA; the code below was what I was planning to write, but it does not work because functions called from a worksheet cannot change the worksheet:

```
Public Function Hypothetical(setthiscell As Range, tothisvalue As Variant, andobservethiscell As Range) As Variant
    Dim oldvalue As Variant
    oldvalue = setthiscell.Value
    setthiscell.Value = tothisvalue
    Dim result As Variant
    result = andobservethiscell.Value
    setthiscell.Value = oldvalue
    Hypothetical = result
End Function
```

Neither Scenarios or the Solver address my problem because I want to the solution to be automated.  Apparently the *only* way to accomplish this task is to use data tables.